# Possibly unstable output of linear power supply due to very large current amplfication

Tags: power-supply, power, current, amplifier, linear

I'm designing a linear power supply with an op-amp as error amp and a Sziklai pair as output stage as a hobby project (see schematic below).

I'm worried, that the output Vo will be unstable/unpredictable due to the very large current amplification from the output of U1 to the output of the power supply Vo. Maybe leakage and/or noise currents will be enough the turn the output on.

I have simulated the circuit in Orcad Pspice, and there it works fine, but I fear that it will not in practice.

Has anyone an idea how to remedy the potential problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you run a stability analysis on the loop showing the (current) loop gain and phase margin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as you said, the gain of the 4 BJTs combined is huge and results in a **severely unstable circuit**, irrespective of the local compensation. Trust me, I have tried. When you simulated the circuit, you must have connected the input of the voltage regulator to a pure DC source, which has absolutely no ripple. Due to this, your op amp just has to maintain a steady output voltage to drive the BJTs to get the desired output voltage. The problem arises in the real world where PSU noise is unavoidable and the op amps have a finite value of PSRR (power supply rejection ratio). Due to this, the op amp must vary its output to compensate for the PSU ripple. But in doing so, even the smallest variations in the op amp's output is amplified greatly by the BJTs and results in **severe instability**. The following LTspice simulations demonstrate that.

This is a simulation with a **pure DC input**

[image]

As you can see, the output is a clean 5V DC, as you would expect.

Now, I have added 200mVpp 100kHz of input ripple:

[image]

As you can see, the output has gone nuts. The output has over 350mVpp of ripple!!

Now you might say, "Let's add some output capacitance to bring down the ripple!"

So here's the result of that:

[image]

The o/p ripple has indeed decreased, but look at the collector current of the series pass transistor:

[image]

The collector current has a 0.6A swing, which the capacitor absorbs!

Now here's a better voltage regulator scheme:

[image]

In this scheme, a current source (which you can easily make using 2 PNP BJTs) feeds the series pass transistor is shunted to control the amount of current going into the base of the pass transistor. By controlling the base current of the pass tranny, the collector current and hence the output voltage can be controlled. This is much more stable and has a good ripple rejection.

And here is the collector current of the pass tranny:

[image]

There is only 10mA of swing, compared to last time's 0.6A!

Answer (score 1):

There's way too much gain, this will never work.

First rule of designing a regulator is know your load impedance. There will usually be at least one capacitor on the output, most likely several. Some loads are tricky, like DC-DC converters which can have negative input impedance (VCC goes down, current goes up). If there are wires between regulator and load, add some inductance.

If the regulator, the load and the capacitors are part of the same design, then the regulator can be optimized for these parameters. Otherwise, it has to be designed to work with a range of loads and capacitors.

So get an idea of the range of impedance curve vs frequency you want it to work with. If you design a bench power supply, that's quite a wide range.

If the load is connected via something that has low inductance, like power/ground planes, then it's on the same board, so you design it together, that's easier.

If the load is connected via wires (inductance) then the HF output impedance of the power supply is irrelevant for load regulation, it will be dominated by wire inductance anyway. And if you expect ceramic capacitors on the load side, then your power supply can't have low impedance at high frequency (ie, ceramic caps on the output) otherwise you're building a series LC resonator with the wires. So it's safer to have a flat resistive output impedance at HF, say an electrolytic cap with ESR around 1 ohm or above, or a bunch of MLCCs with resistors in series. This has the advantage that the regulator now faces a known load impedance at HF, if the wires are long enough to have enough inductance to isolate it from low HF load impedance.

So, top right we have a load, a bunch of caps stepped through a list of values with ESR and ESL, and on the left, its impedance is in blue. The 50nH inductor and 10mOhm resistor are the wires.

Bottom right we have a regulator which is (for now) just a 350nH inductor. Combined with the various simulated load impedances, this forms some nicely damped combinations if the load capacitors are large, but if they are small, there is ringing.

[image]

This needs damping, so let's add some shunt resistive impedance to our regulator, something like a 0.1 Ohm 220µF capacitor with rather irrelevant inductance. I've also stepped the wire inductance.

[image]

This is much better damped. So, let's get rid of the load and display the target regulator output impedance. I've added a 1µF, 1 ohm cap too.

[image]

Now you can synthetize that any way you want. There will be a pass transistor and an error amp to provide current to the load and to synthetize the inductive (350nH) part of the impedance. The damping can be provided by an output cap, or it can be done by the control loop too, if you want a very fast overcurrent protection. Because if the power supply is set to 40V, 20mA and you plug in a LED thinking "hey it's on current limit what could go wrong", if the output capacitance is implemented with a capacitor it will discharge into the LED and possibly fry it. Otherwise if the damping part of the impedance curve is not implemented with a big cap, but with a smart control loop instead, then there is no charged capacitor to fry your LED.

Designing a competent bench power supply is rather tricky because there are two control loops (current and voltage) and how fast, and how well it switches between the two without anything going wrong sorts out the winners from the losers.

So, ok, I did not answer the question exactly, but this is where you should start.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what U1 is, but it probably is compensated for unity gain or low-gain applications.  However, Q1, Q2, and Q4 are uncompensated voltage gain stages within the U1 feedback loop.  Local degeneration will help tame things, but even if it runs cleanly you still should do a full stability analysis to see how close to the edge you are skating.

Comment: And make sure to do the stability analysis into a variety of loads.  Better yet, run the thing into a constant-current load (i.e., use a current source that pulls current out of the supply).  Do an AC analysis with your load as the source, and plot the voltage output vs. the current.  If it shifts by more than 90 degrees, that means that there's some capacitive or inductive load you can put on the thing that'll make it oscillate.

Answer (score 0):

U1 has some slew-rate limiting, probably, but with Q1 wired as shown,
that doesn't help.   Reduce the voltage gain at Q1 by putting
an emitter resistor into the circuit, such that U1 doesn't have
enough voltage range on its output to saturate the Q1 transistor... which
would be bad for regulation.

An emitter resistor for Q2 might be useful as well, but that will
dissipate some power if it is needed.   The op amp is likely to
work best if its internal voltage gain dominates (rather than
the gain of the added transistors) so that the internal  amplifier
compensation is effective.

A Bode plot with a few sample load impedances would be a very useful
simulation procedure.